# Objective C code , showing footer view cell in table view , but hide when keyboard resign

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a table view with footer view it works fine but when i click on footer view text field and then dismissed keyboard ,footer view gets hide shown in fig.
 I'am using this code for showing footer view.

```
- (UIView )tableView:(UITableView )tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    EditDetailCellFooter *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"editCellFooter"];
    cell.delegate= self;
    return cell;

}
```

[image]

After dismissing keyboard footer view gets disappear when scroll table view it come again.

[image]

Please Help Thanks in advance.

> **Blockquote**

Comment: Return `UIView` from `viewForFooterInSection` method not the subclass of  `UITableViewCell`. You can also return this cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: How i can return cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath for footer view

Comment: have you reload the table when dismiss the keyboard? @Amitgupta

Comment: Return this cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as your last cell.

Comment: Thanks @sunny  for your help i returned , cell.content view and  its working fine now.

Comment: Yes @saurabhJain I have reload it . But still I have this problem .But thanks for quick responce

Comment: @Amitgupta have you find the solution as sunny suggestion?

Comment: @Saurabh Sunny answer work now my footer view not disappear but my delegates not worked now like now I'm not able to perform action on save button and cancel button .If I use your suggestion reload table view then my all values are empty after reloading table

Comment: @Amitgupta have you heard about the table footer view not section footer?